# Encrypting And Decrypting data in keil

Tags: c, embedded, iot, public-key-encryption, keil

Can I encrypt binary code in keil software itself? Are there any other options I can encrypt my binary code and send the encrypted code to some other place?

Comment: Encrypt for what purpose? For sending to someone else via email? For storing in file system? Who would decrypt it?

Comment: Are you looking at encrypting your compiled firmware? I don't think that the Keil development environment supports directly. It would need to be a post build stage. You could trigger a script file that would perform the encryption for you.

Answer (score 0):

Write encrypting program (or use any available on the market) and run a post buid step.

More info: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101407/0537/Dialogs/Project/Options/User?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manual or link post build steps with some executable (there are lot of open source software for encrypt, decrypt. And some already available in your PC) to perform this.

Comment: Can you give some examples of those softwares?

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-command-prompt-encrypt-files/